# Break JS when a cookie is set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, firefox, html

I am attempting to debug a webpage. However I cannot find what sets a specific cookie. I know the name of the cookie, so I am asking if there is a way to break the JS code when the cookie is set to show me which bit of code is setting it.